# FLV Files Open in browser (text) no download prompted

Tags: video, video-hosting

I'm just wondering if there's a certain setting on my server or something that is causing flv files to open in the browser when you go to then, and display all the gibberish text rather than prompt for download or begin playing in the default media player.

Anyone got any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't set a correct [Content type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME) on the server.